# how to remove "essential_grid" from url on essential grid post permalink

Tags: php, wordpress

How to remove this permalink as i mentioned bellow...
the first link making my site wired. I want to get rid off this. But the theme documentation doesn't provide too much acknowledgement about this.

```
https://abcxyz.com/essential_grid/myproject/
```

to

```
https://abcxyz.com/myproject/
```

Comment: as per your URL `essential_grid` is category and `myproject` is post slug am i right?

Comment: Yes. @RenishKhunt.

Comment: Hey Rabib. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and provide further information (e.g. things you already tried that didnt work) to help others to understand your problem and question better.

Comment: Hi Rabib, you should change your site permalink structure from wordpress admin goto settings > Permalink. and change your permalink structure